# Add fast view in application workbench and add view in it

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, perspective

I have rcp application which have several views. I want to add a fast view option as eclipse ide has so that i can poulate all my views in it.

I have tried all possible ways which are as follows:

add entry in plugin.xml

```
<extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.perspectiveExtensions">
      <perspectiveExtension
            targetID="my.ui.Perspective">
         <view
               closeable="true"
               id="my.Explorer"
               minimized="false"
               moveable="true"
               ratio="0.95f"
               relationship="fast"
               relative="org.eclipse.ui.editorss"
               showTitle="true"
               standalone="true"
               visible="true">
         </view>
      </perspectiveExtension>
   </extension>
```

and done changes in applicationworkbenchadvisor

```
@Override
public void preWindowOpen(IWorkbenchWindowConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.setInitialSize(new Point(1024, 800));
    configurer.setShowStatusLine(true);
    configurer.setTitle("My application");
    configurer.setShowFastViewBars(true);
}
```

but its not showing not even any exception is throwing.

please count what i doing wrong ASAP.

Comment: You have a misspelling relative="org.eclipse.ui.editorss"

Comment: Which version of Eclipse. The very latest versions don't support Fast Views any more.

Comment: @greg-449 its eclipse 3.5. if it is not posible then what are the other ways to get have short cut other then show view option.